# Por que a expressão (double.MinValue == double.MinValue + 1) é verdadeira?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, ponto-flutuante

O seguinte código C#:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(double.MinValue == double.MinValue + 1);
        Console.WriteLine(int.MinValue == int.MinValue + 1);
    }
}
```

tem como saída:

```
True
False
```

Minha pergunta é: por que a primeira linha retorna `true`? Para mim, esta linha deveria retornar `false`, visto que estou comparando um número com ele mesmo + 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primeiro leia [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Ali diz que não é possível representar todos os números em formato binário. Então alguns números são tomados por aproximação. Note que existem 308 dígitos neste número ele vale -1.79769313486232E+308.

Como esse tipo de dado não tem exatidão quando você tem um número com um valor no extremo, muito baixo ou muito alto, somar 1 não muda de fato o valor, em uma quantidade tão grande a representação binária não consegue diferenciar um número do outro, os bits de ambos são os mesmos.

Pensa bem, um `long` tem o mesmo tamanho que um `double`, como este último consegue representar muito mais inteiros e uma quantidade absurda de números fracionários com a mesma quantidade de bits de um inteiro? Simples, ele não representa todos esses números, apenas aproximações deles, aí números muito próximos na verdade possuem a mesma representação binária, não há diferença sequer de 1 bit entre eles, então você consegue obter grandeza suficiente para números bem amplos, mas não consegue o número exato, é como se ele pegasse só uma amostragem.

Por isso que eu sempre digo que se a exatidão for importante não use um número de ponto flutuante codificado binariamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só porque eu gosto desse vídeo e explica exatamente o que você disse, para quem quiser mais informação futura: https://youtu.be/pQs_wx8eoQ8

Comment: Na sére de jogos Mass Effect tem um ecossistema inteiro de inteligências artificiais que se divide entre os que querem destruir todas as formas de vida e os que não, e a cisma toda ocorre por causa de uma diferença de na enésima casa decimal de uma divisão com ponto flutuante. Pensem nisso quando precisão for importante.