# Qual o melhor tipo para armazenar área, volume e perímetro?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, tipagem

`Decimal`, `Numeric` ou `Float`, qual a melhor opção para armazenar área ou volume?

Eu usaria o `Decimal`, mas gostaria de ver a opinião de outros também.

Parece que não, mas o tipo certo ou o mais próximo disso faz toda a diferença, até porque apanhei com um banco com tipos `REAL` e não quero perder tempo com tipos errados. Usei [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) pois nela irei mapear os tipos do banco pelo C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

De forma geral o `decimal` é o mais correto. Mesmo que não precise da [exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146157/101) dele se interagir com outras unidades que precisam, a ruim contamina a boa e tudo fica errado.

De forma geral eu vejo zero vantagens em usar um [tipo de ponto flutuante binário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239180/101). Sim, pode ter mais performance e deve ocupar menos memória, mas o risco é muito grande, principalmente na mão de programadores que não são muito afiados em desenvolvimento de software e façam tudo com muita minúcia, com profundo entendimento de todas as consequências. E tudo seja absurdamente bem documentado, o que nunca acontece.

Veja mais em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

É pouco difundido mas existe os tipos espaciais no C#. Claro que é possível trabalhar com qualquer tipo de dado com ponto flutuante, mas além de armazenar certamente você vai querer fazer cálculos com estes pontos.
Já precisei para um trabalho acadêmico e foi uma mão na roda.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/modeling/spatial